# How to stretch individual background images in CSS

Tags: html, css

```
background: url(timages/wb-right.png) 100% 0 no-repeat, url(timages/wb-left.png) 0 0 no-repeat, url(timages/wb-top.png) 0 0 no-repeat, url(timages/wb-bottom.png) 0 80px no-repeat;
```

I currently have this code specifying 4 images for the background of a box. There is one for each side. Left Top Right Bottom.

The only issue is the Top and Bottom images do not stretch or repeat the full width of the box. Is this possible to do. If I set any of the no-repeats to repeat it fills the entire background.

Any advice helpful

Comment: Could you provide a JsFiddle or an url?

Comment: Not url....that makes question usefulness very limited to any future visitor...please provide a fiddle!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for something like this: ?

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/dgcfK/**

```
background-image: url(timages/wb-top.png), 
    url(timages/wb-left.png), 
    url(timages/wb-right.png), 
    url(timages/wb-bottom.png);
background-position: left top, left bottom, top right, bottom right;
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y, repeat-x;
```